# Load dropdown list from class asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a dropdown list on a view, this view adds users to the database. The dropdown list code is currently in the **CreateUser()** method in the users controller, and it works perfectly. I need to reuse this code throughout the application, so I created a new Class called stores and have created a method called **LoadStoreList()** and have moved the code from CreateUser() to this new method. The idea is obviously to call this LoadStoreList() method every time I need to poplate a drop down with the list of stores.

**Controller**
I want to call the LoadStoreList() method from the CreateUser() method.

```
public IActionResult CreateUser()
{
    var getStoreList = new Stores();
    ViewBag.Stores = getStoreList.LoadStoreList();
    return View();
}
```

**Stores Class**

```
public class Stores
{
    private static ApplicationDbContext? _context;

    public Stores()
    {
    }

    public Stores(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult LoadStoreList()
    {
        var storeList = _context?.Stores.Select
                        (s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.StoreId.ToString(), Text = s.StoreName }).ToList();
        storeList?.Insert(0, new SelectListItem("-- Select --", ""));
        return (IActionResult)storeList;
    }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that the storeList object in the LoadStoreList method is always null , and I can't quite see where I'm going wrong.

**Edit**

```
private static ApplicationDbContext _context;

public Stores()
{
    _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
}
```

Comment: Because  your `_context` is null in  your Stores.

Comment: Why aren't you using `interfaces`? and creating tight coupling on your `class` where `CreateUser()` is located? I would assume you might want to re-use that `LoadStoresList` multiple times. Will you be creating a new instance every time?

Comment: Hi @QingGuo, I see the problem. I have 2 constructors and the empty one is executing instead of the one that sets the ApplicationDbContext. Once I remove the empty one, I then have an issue on the method call, I get this error "Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'context' of 'Stores.Stores(ApplicationDbContext)'". I understand when I'm getting this error, I'm going to try and initialize the dbContext outside of the parameters.

Comment: Hi @ThisQRequiresASpecialist, thats probably the better way to go, but I'm new to C# and still learning, I plan to tackle intervaces as I gain more experience.

Comment: I'd highly, highly recommend getting to know `SOLID` [principle](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/conceptual-articles/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).  And get into interfaces ASAP, they will make your life easier and you'll be able to avoid more mistakes that you'll regret in next 10 hours of coding.

Comment: How  you define your `_context?.Stores.` ? Could you share your code?

Comment: Hi @QingGuo, I've added an Edit to my original post with what i'm trying. I realized that I have to initialize the applicationDbContext in this class. I'm thinking I need to call my connection string in the overload ? but there's so many overload options that i'm not too sure what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try:

1.make some change to your controller(replace LoopDroController with your controller):

```
 public class LoopDroController : Controller
        {
            private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
            public LoopDroController(ApplicationDbContext context)
            {
                _context = context;
            }
                     
            public IActionResult CreateUser()
            {
                var getStoreList = new Stores(_context);
                ViewBag.Stores = getStoreList.LoadStoreList();
                return View();
            }
        }
```

2.change your stores like below:

```
 public class Stores
    {
        private static ApplicationDbContext? _context;
        public Stores(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public List<SelectListItem> LoadStoreList()
        {
            ar storeList = _context?.Stores.Select
                    (s => new SelectListItem { Value = s.StoreId.ToString(), Text = s.StoreName }).ToList();
            storeList?.Insert(0, new SelectListItem("-- Select --", ""));
            return storeList;
        }
    }
```

3.result:

[image]